# boost module - no file to Disallow: /boost_stats.php

Tags: 7, caching

I have followed the installation guidelines and installed [Boost](http://drupal.org/project/boost), but where it states to add a line 'Disallow: /boost_stats.php' for robots.txt doesnt seem to make sense as I dont have a boost_stats.php file in root for search engines not to follow anyway. Do I really need to add this line?

Answer (score 2):

This file was a part of the Boost module in Drupal 6. It is no longer present in the Drupal 7 version. If you are using D7 this instruction can be ignored.

Comment: thats brill - thanks, I suspected that, but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: I always added it to robots.txt just to keep my Status Report page clean! :P If the file doesn't exist, I don't see how it makes any difference.